# Excluding from animation block

Tags: iphone, animation

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
...
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

For example I need to animate frame's width conditionally, along with the rest of other modifications which are mandatory. The reason I can't put the code out of this block, because there is a function call within the block.
How would I exclude some operations from within animation block?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you are trying to have as an end result.  What are you trying to exclude?

Comment: Updated, let me know if still not clear.

Comment: As a result I want to animate most of the properties in that block and apply immediate change without animation to some of them.

Comment: What is the problem of simply putting *immediate change* code outside (e.g. in front of) the block?

Comment: @Horace Ho: like I said in my original post - there are function calls where I can't extract only those parts which needs immediate change and put outside of the block, it will make it too complex and redundant. Moreover, they are conditional and I will figure out they are animated or not only once the functions are called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout `setAnimationsEnabled`:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Ani" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
  // some animations
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
  // animations disabled (put exclusions here)
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
  // some more animations
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I did before writing and it says: `Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods instead.`

Comment: It's discouraged, but still supported ;-)

Comment: Thank you, simple and very effective when you need something changed immediatelly, yet you are within a block opened elsewhere and can't control wether it will be animated or not.

Comment: In willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation you have no other option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the blocks based way:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    view.frame = CGRectMake(...);
}];
```